Computing inverse of a matrix without needing too much memory
I have matrix that is $36\times36$ and it has a structure as below
$$
  M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   B1 & B2 & B3 & B4 & B5 & B6\\
   B2^H & B1 & B2 & B3 & B4 & B5\\
   B3^H & B2^H & B1 & B2 & B3 & B4\\
   B4^H & B3^H & B2^H & B1 & B2 & B3\\
   B5^H & B4^H & B3^H & B2^H & B1 & B2\\
   B6^H & B5^H & B4^H & B3^H & B2^H & B1\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$
where each $B_i$ is a $6\times6$ matrix, $B_1$ is Hermitian symmetric and $B_i^H$ is hermitian transpose of $B_i$. I want to compute the inverse of $M$ without needing to have all the elements of $M$ at once. Is there any iterative way that I can compute the inverse of $M$ with only having partial elements of $M$ at each iteration?

You could maybe do blockwise inversion on 18 x 18 matrices. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion
